# Preg_replace - Preserve line breaks and Sanitize some text

Tags: php, regex

```
$txt_unclean = trim(nl2br($_POST['txt_content']));
$txt_content = strip_tags($txt_unclean, '<b><i><u><br>');
$txt_br_replace = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9 \!\,\?\.\n s]/", '', preg_replace("!(<br(?:\s?/)?>\s*){2,}!s", "<br />\n<br />\n", $txt_content));
```

Okay. So I'm allowing only 2 line break per line breaks. For example, If there are 9 line breaks, then it would replace it with two line breaks. Doing that alone, I get successful results. However, the problem is when I want to clean up the words using this regex: `/[^a-zA-Z0-9 \!\,\?\.\n s]/`

It basically deletes all the line breaks but cleans up the words. So how do I preserve the line breaks?

For example:
I want this:

```
StackOverflow is amazing@$#@#$#@#@#@!#@@!




I KNOW!@$!##$$#!!#$@(*$09@*
```

According to the Regex I wrote, this should be the output:

```
StackOverflow is amazing!!


I KNOW!!!!09
```

Comment: can you show an example of the original string and how you want it to look like

Comment: I have updated it. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

use filter_var function to sanitize variables, link to docs below.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

> It basically deletes all the line breaks but cleans up the words. So
>   how do I preserve the line breaks?

Replace \s+ by one "space".

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I manage to make it work. 
If there are any flaws in it, please do inform me.

Here is the variable that I changed:

```
$txt_br_replace = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9 \!\,\?\.\r\n s (<br>)]/", '', preg_replace("!(<br(?:\s?/)?>\s*){2,}!s", "<br />\n<br />\n", $txt_content));
```